# logistic regression alternative interpretation

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to analyze the data that shows people catch the disease or not. That is, response is binary. I applied logistic regression. Assume the result of the `log.reg` (logistic regression) is like;

```
ID = c(1,2,3,4)
Test_Data = c(0,1,1,0)
Log.Reg_Output = c(0.01,0.4,0.8,0.49)
result = data.frame(ID,Test_Data,Reg_Output)

result

# 1   | 0 |  0.01  
# 2   | 1 |  0.4    
# 3   | 1 |  0.8    
# 4   | 0 |  0.49
```

Can I say that person who has ID=3 will catch the disease at 80 percent? Is it right approach? If not, why? I am so confused, any help will be great!

Second question is how can I calculate accuracy rate except rounding the model result 0 or 1. Because rounding 0.49 to 0 is not so meaningful I think.
For my example, model output will turn 0,0,1,0 instead 0.01, 0.4, 0.8, 0.49 based on greater or less than 0.5. And accuracy rate will be 75%. Is there any other calculation method?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the log loss score, I think you are looking for a different scoring metric

Comment: Take a look at wiki for the explanation and interpretation of logistic regression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function,_odds,_odds_ratio,_and_logit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I say that person who has ID=3 will catch the disease at 80 percent?

It is unclear what you mean by "at"; the traditional/conventional interpretation of the logistic regression output here is *the model estimates that person #3 will catch the disease, with 80% confidence*. It is also unclear what you mean by "alternative" in your title (you don't elaborate in the question body).

> how can I calculate accuracy rate except rounding the model result 0 or 1.

Accuracy *by definition* requires rounding the model results to 0/1. But, at least in principle, the decision threshold need not necessarily be 0.5...

> Because rounding 0.49 to 0 is not so meaningful I think.

Do you think rounding 0.49 to 1 is more meaningful? Because this is the only alternative choice in a binary classification setting (a person *either* will catch the disease, *or* not).

Regarding the log loss metric, mentioned in the comments: its role is completely different than that of the accuracy. You may find these relevant answers of mine helpful:

[Loss & accuracy - Are these reasonable learning curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817424/loss-accuracy-are-these-reasonable-learning-curves/47819022#47819022)

[How does Keras evaluate the accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508874/how-does-keras-evaluate-the-accuracy/47515095#47515095) (despite the mislading title, it has nothing particular to do with Keras).

I seriously suggest you have a look at some logistic regression tutorials (there are literally hundreds out there); a highly recommended source is the textbook [An Introduction to Statistical Learning (with Applications in R)](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), made freely available by the authors...

Comment: links that you suggested are so helpful. Thank you so much!