# Why roc_auc produces weird results in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, auc

I have a binary classification problem where I use the following code to get my `weighted avarege precision`, `weighted avarege recall`, `weighted avarege f-measure` and `roc_auc`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_path+input_file)

X = df[features]
y = df[["gold_standard"]]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring = ('accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted', 'roc_auc'))

print("accuracy")
print(np.mean(scores['test_accuracy'].tolist()))
print("precision_weighted")
print(np.mean(scores['test_precision_weighted'].tolist()))
print("recall_weighted")
print(np.mean(scores['test_recall_weighted'].tolist()))
print("f1_weighted")
print(np.mean(scores['test_f1_weighted'].tolist()))
print("roc_auc")
print(np.mean(scores['test_roc_auc'].tolist()))
```

I got the following results for the same dataset with 2 different feature settings.

```
Feature setting 1 ('accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted', 'roc_auc'):  
0.6920, 0.6888, 0.6920, 0.6752, 0.7120

Feature setting 2 ('accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted', 'roc_auc'):
0.6806  0.6754  0.6806  0.6643  0.7233
```

So, we can see that in `feature setting 1` we get good results for 'accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted' compared to `feature setting 2`.

However, when it comes to 'roc_auc' `feature setting 2` is better than `feature setting 1`. I found this weird becuase every other metric was better with `feature setting 1`.

On one hand, I suspect that this happens since I am using `weighted` scores for `precision, recall and f-measure` and not with `roc_auc`. Is it possible to do `weighted roc_auc` for binary classification in sklearn?

What is the real problem for this weird `roc_auc` results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not weird, because comparing all these other metrics with AUC is like comparing apples to oranges.

Here is a high-level description of the whole process:

- Probabilistic classifiers (like RF here) produce probability outputs `p` in `[0, 1]`.
- To get hard class predictions (`0/1`), we apply a *threshold* to these probabilities; if not set explicitly (like here), this threshold is implicitly taken to be 0.5, i.e. if `p>0.5` then `class=1`, else `class=0`.
- Metrics like accuracy, precision, recall, and f1-score are calculated over the hard class predictions `0/1`, i.e *after* the threshold has been applied.
- In contrast, AUC measures the performance of a binary classifier averaged over the *range of all possible thresholds*, and not for a particular threshold.

So, it can certainly happen, and it can indeed lead to confusion among new practitioners.

The second part of my answer in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610117/comparing-auc-log-loss-and-accuracy-scores-between-models/58612125#58612125) might be helpful for more details. Quoting:

> According to my experience at least, most ML practitioners think that the AUC score measures something different from what it *actually* does: the common (and unfortunate) use is just like any other the-higher-the-better metric, like accuracy, which may naturally lead to puzzles like the one you express yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Thant makes sense. I want to identify the most suitable feature setting for my problem. In that case, would you recommend me to go with `roc_auc` scores and select `feature setting 2` or vice versa? Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you :)

Comment: @EmJ I think the very last part of the linked thread implies an answer ;)

Comment: hehe, ya I figured it out. Thank you for the wonderful answer that you linked. I learnt a lot form it. I have one last question that I thought would be great to get your feedback. I noted that my `accuracy` is always similar to my `weighted recall` value. This makes me really worried. Do you know why this happens? Thank you :)

Comment: @EmJ sorry, not quite sure - check the definition in the docs