# Optimum Weight update in CNN training

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I have two networks. `D->C1,R1->P1->C2,R2->loss and D->C1,R1,C2,R2->P1->C3,R3->loss`.

D is data, C for Conv, R for Relu and P for Pool.

I trained first network from scratch and since two networks have only C2,R2 layers are different, I used all weights from first network and train only C2. C1 and C3 are set with lr_mult=0.So their weights are not updated.

My query is how can I know C2 has optimum weight to stop training.

Say network 1 has mAP=0.85 after 5 epochs. When I train network 2, it has mAP=0.86 just after 1 epoch.

When should I stop training in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, neural network optimization in general [is non-convex](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106334/cost-function-of-neural-network-is-non-convex), so it is impossible to know if a particular local minima is a global minima [*] The fact that you have pretrained weights isn't particularly relevant [**] . The type of [solver has an effect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90874/how-can-stochastic-gradient-descent-avoid-the-problem-of-a-local-minimum)

That said, there are some criteria that are occasionally used heuristically. Importantly: [use a testing set, not a training set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009971/2329988) for evaluation (and then use a separate validation set when checking your performance).

1. Change in [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) on the testing set plateus
2. Cross valdiation [***]
3. The learning rate vanishes ([depends on your solver](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/solver.html))
4. A fixed number of iterations

Here's one [slightly older survey](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5530351), though results tend to always be empirical

---

Additionally, [Goodfellow](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html) makes the following important recommendation about making sure your parameters are as optimal as possible regardless of your criteria:

> Every time the error on the validation set improves, we store a copy
>   of the model parameters. When the training algorithm terminates, we
>   return these parameters, rather than the latest parameters. The
>   algorithm terminates when no parameters have improved over the best
>   recorded validation error for some pre-specified number of iterations

---

---

#### Footnotes

[*] There are other conditions ([e.g](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/96/n090p101.pdf)) that might provide this information, but none of them apply

[**] I'm not aware that there's research on this one way or another, but I would suspect that it would actually make the problem *harder*, as you're starting from a pretty good local minima that may be hard to climb out of

[***] This is not the same as using cross validation to measure accuracy on a testing set or for model selection, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56421/is-it-ok-to-determine-early-stopping-using-the-validation-set-in-10-fold-cross-v)