# Are my training and validation code (tensorflow) right and does the model overfit?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

This is my code:

```
for it in range(EPOCH*24410//BATCH_SIZE):
    tr_pa, tr_sp = sess.run([tr_para, tr_spec])
    train_loss, _ = sess.run([loss, fw_op], feed_dict={x: tr_pa, y: tr_sp})
    train_loss_.append(train_loss)
    it_tr.append(it)

    va_pa, va_sp = sess.run([va_para, va_spec])
    validate_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: va_pa, y: va_sp})
    validate_loss_.append(validate_loss)
```

This is the training loss and validation loss:

[image]

My question is whether my validation code right or not. And does this model overfit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The telltale **signature** of overfitting is when your validation loss starts increasing, while your training loss continues decreasing, i.e.:

[image: adapted from Wikipedia]

(Image adapted from Wikipedia entry on [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting))

Here are some other plots indicating overfitting ([source](https://forums.fast.ai/t/determining-when-you-are-overfitting-underfitting-or-just-right/7732/8)):

[image]

[image]

See also the SO thread [How to know if underfitting or overfitting is occuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009816/how-to-know-if-underfitting-or-overfitting-is-occuring/52009971).

Clearly, your plot does not exhibit such behavior, hence you are not overfitting.

Your code looks OK, keeping in mind that you don't show what exactly goes on inside your session `sess`.