# Loss curve in multilabel classification with high class imbalance

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am working on multilabel classification problem. The classes are highly imbalance. However, I balanced the imbalance problem with class weights. I am using "Binary cross entropy" as cost funtion and sigmoid activation function at output layer. But, I am confused with loss curve (since the validation loss and testing loss are parallel ). Is this the case of overfitting?

[image]

Comment: Yes, It is  a 12 class multilabel classification problem, in which one class contains 4096 (class with highest instance ) instances, one of the other class contains 76 (class with lowest instance) instances, and other classes contain instances between 76 to 4096.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The telltale **signature** of overfitting is when your validation loss starts increasing, while your training loss continues decreasing, i.e.:

[image: adapted from Wikipedia]

(Image adapted from Wikipedia entry on [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting))

Here are some other plots indicating overfitting ([source](https://forums.fast.ai/t/determining-when-you-are-overfitting-underfitting-or-just-right/7732/8)):

[image]

[image]

See also the SO thread [How to know if underfitting or overfitting is occuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009816/how-to-know-if-underfitting-or-overfitting-is-occuring/52009971).

Clearly, your plot does not exhibit such behavior, hence you are not overfitting.