# Is this overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a CNN that is performing very well (96% accuracy, 1.~ loss) on training data but poorly (50% accuracy, 3.5 loss) on testing data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it likely is overfitting

Comment: If it's basically guessing on the test data, then yes. Try adding dropout and/or regularization layers.

Comment: I already add dropout layer and regularization l2 .

Comment: @SamAtWork Excuse me.I change my model.And this is my result. https://imgur.com/u3aHvyc https://imgur.com/KeTPiLB I want to ask that is it overfitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The telltale **signature** of overfitting is when your validation loss starts increasing, while your training loss continues decreasing, i.e.:

[image: adapted from Wikipedia]

(Image adapted from Wikipedia entry on [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting))

Here are some other plots indicating overfitting ([source](https://forums.fast.ai/t/determining-when-you-are-overfitting-underfitting-or-just-right/7732/8)):

[image]

[image]

See also the SO thread [How to know if underfitting or overfitting is occuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009816/how-to-know-if-underfitting-or-overfitting-is-occuring/52009971).

Clearly, your loss plot **does** exhibit such behavior, so yes, you are indeed overfitting.

On the contrary, the plot you have linked to in a comment:

[image]

does not exhibit such behavior, hence here you are **not** actually overfitting (you just have reached a saturation point, beyond which your validation error is not further improving).

Answer (score 0):

96% accuracy suggests you have a really close fit to your training data. 50% accuracy on testing data shows that your model cannot account for the noise/variability of the data being studied. This looks like textbook overfitting.

You seem to be calling your validation data your test data. Maybe you can better partition your data?

Comment: Should I change my model?Or add more data?

Comment: First I would change your model. Maybe experiment with cross-validation. I don't know how much data you're using so I don't know about the last question.

Comment: I will try it.Thanks.

Comment: By the way my data is imbalance.Could you give me any suggestion?

Comment: Here is a good guide I found for handling imbalanced data. : https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Comment: excuse me.I change my model.And this is my result. https://imgur.com/u3aHvyc
    https://imgur.com/KeTPiLB
I want to ask that is it overfitting?

Comment: Good job, that looks much better than the original. It could be overfitting but it's hard to say. I would make a new post with your new model.