# Evaluation of an ANN Linear Regression Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, regression

I have made my first ANN with Keras. It's a Linear Regression Model with 5 features and 1 output. I made a plot with "MSE" and "Loss function" and these are the results. Can we say that it is a good model? In addition R^2 = 0.91 .
Is this the right way?

```
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(5, input_dim=5,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))


classifier.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])

history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=200, verbose=0)

y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)

train_mse=classifier.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)

plt.title('Loss / Mean Squared Error')
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from some terminology details (NN regression is not *linear* regression, and usually we don't call such model a `classifier`), your model looks good indeed, with both errors (training & test) reducing smoothly and no signs of [overfitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780450/is-this-overfitting/56805078#56805078).

Although  an R^2 value of 0.91 sounds pretty good, the use of the metric in *predictive* settings, like here, is quite problematic; quoting from my own answer in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct/54618898#54618898):

> the whole R-squared concept comes in fact directly from the world of statistics, where the emphasis is on *interpretative* models, and it has little use in machine learning contexts, where the emphasis is clearly on *predictive* models; at least AFAIK, and beyond some very introductory courses, I have never (I mean *never*...) seen a predictive modeling problem where the R-squared is used for any kind of performance assessment; neither it's an accident that popular *machine learning* introductions, such as Andrew Ng's [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) at Coursera, do not even bother to mention it. And, as noted in the [Github thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5570) above (emphasis added):
>
> > In particular when using a **test** set, it's a bit unclear to me what the R^2 means.
>
> with which I certainly concur.