# Siamese Network-Train own datasets and judged overfitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, siamese-network, overfitting-underfitting

I use Siamese Network to train my own dataset.I visualized the training results using Tensorboard.I'm a beginner and I'm not very good at judging if it's an overfit.Please help to see, thank you!
Figure 1 and 2 are Train.
Figure 3 and 4 are Validation.
[image: Figure 1 This is the accuracy of the training set]

[image: Figure 2 Train Loss]
[image: Figure 3 The accuracy of the Validation set]
[image: Figure 4 Validation Loss]

Comment: Those pictures without legend or axis labels won't make sense to anyone. About overfitting and underfitting, please google https://machinelearningmastery.com/overfitting-and-underfitting-with-machine-learning-algorithms/

Comment: hi.I looked at the link you shared.But I'm a little confused about how to judge.How do I tell if I'm overfitting?
Do you just look at the predictions?Looking forward to your reply. Thank you

Comment: What makes you confused? What's your current understanding about overfitting or underfitting?

Comment: My understanding is that an overfit is a function that is not fitted, and when I look at Figure 3, it looks a bit like an overfit.

Comment: I see. Please see this QnA, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009816/how-to-know-if-underfitting-or-overfitting-is-occuring

Comment: I understand after reading your share, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your network does NOT appear to be over fitting. A classic sign of over fitting is when your training loss continues to decrease while your validation loss begins and continues rising

Comment: Thank you for your reply, which is very useful to me.