# Find accuracy/loss of specific data point in validation set in semantic segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training a fairly large keras unet model with some obscure data to do **semantic image segmentation**. The val_loss decreases initially but after some hours it starts to shoot up. It was likely overfitting and I put in more data only to delay the same behavior.

I want to observe what is going on in the validation stage. Is it possible to output a **"per sample accuracy and loss"** after each epoch since val_loss and val_accuracy is computed after each epoch not batch?

To put it another way, I want to find out *the sample (let's assume image or numpy array) that gives the highest accuracy and the lowest accuracy and visualize them*. I already have written a custom data generator from which I can output the file/array name/number that is being processed but what I am looking to do has been explained above.

Quite likely, I need some sort of a callback.

**Clarification** (after comment): by *sample* I mean a *datapoint* (or an *image* in this context) .

The problem at hand is a semantic segmentation problem (with three classes) not a classification one.

*So basically, on a high level, I am trying to ask the question: in my validation set, which image is being quantified to have high accuracy/low loss, so I can do a sanity check to see if the functions are making sense?*

Comment: By *per sample* you actually mean *per epoch*, right? Please edit & update your question to confirm & clarify this (*sample* means something different).

Comment: Hi there. By *sample* I meant a *datapoint* (or an *image* in this context) . Updating the clarification, Appreciate the help.

Comment: So, *per sample accuracy* and *the sample that gives the highest/lowest accuracy* do not make any sense at all; accuracy is the percentage of points correctly classified, and it is meaningless for any single sample. You can, however request these samples regarding the *loss*; own answer in [Loss & accuracy - Are these reasonable learning curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817424/loss-accuracy-are-these-reasonable-learning-curves/47819022#47819022) may help you clarify the issue.

Comment: @desertnaut : Ahh, I see the what confusion here. The problem at hand is a semantic segmentation problem (with three classes) not a classification one. So basically, on a high level, I am asking, in my validation set, which image is being quantified to have high accuracy so I can do a sanity check to see if the functions are making sense. Loss works too. Appreciate the link. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe clarify this explicitly in your post, then, instead of the comments?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Very much appreciate you taking the time. I edited the post. Again, your reply in the link really helped.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible without a custom callback using [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras) with the `update_freq` option.

```
logdir = "./logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir, update_freq=
'batch')

model.fit(..., callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

And open TensorBoard with

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs/scalars
```