# Can and should `class_weight` and `balanced_accuracy_score` be used together for imbalanced data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data

If I train my classifier (say `LogisticRegression()`) with the parameter `class_weight='balanced'` in scikit-learn, should I then use the regular accuracy measure (i.e., `accuracy_score`) or balanced accuracy (i.e., `balanced_accuracy_score`) when my classes are imbalanced in the data set?

In other words, would using one of the two parameters (at training or measurement time) obviate or necessitate using the other?

Comment: Keep in mind that `class_weight` does not apply at inference (if this is what you mean by "measurement time").

Answer (score 0):

The two things, i.e. using `class_weight=balanced`, and the specific accuracy measure (balanced or not) you will choose to assess your results, are actually irrelevant between them.

Starting from the latter: classification performance metrics like the accuracy (in any version) are *not* involved in any way in model fitting -  only the *loss* does; you may find my answer in [Loss & accuracy - Are these reasonable learning curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817424/loss-accuracy-are-these-reasonable-learning-curves/47819022#47819022) useful in clarifying the relation between these two quantities (although the discussion there is about Keras, the rationale is in fact generally applicable). The exact performance metric to choose depends on your actual *business* problem, and it is not actually part of the *modelling* problem. Moreover, as already said, it will not affect the *training* in any way.

Employing `class_weight`, on the other hand, will affect how the algorithm weights the samples belonging to different classes for computing the *loss* during training, and that's all; it is neither applicable during inference (when the classes are actually unknown), nor it has anything to do with how (i.e. using what metric) we will do our performance assessment (which, again, is part of the *business* problem and not the modelling).

All in all, all combinations are in principle valid here: using `class_weight='balanced'` (alone or possibly combined with `sample_weight`) or not with either of the two versions of the accuracy (simple or balanced). Or, to answer the question as posed in the title - *it can, but it doesn't need to*.

Speaking of `sample_weight`: if you choose to use it with the [`fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) method of Logistic Regression, and you furthermore choose to use the balanced accuracy (which [requires](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html) a `sample_weight` argument), it would certainly sound reasonable to use common values for both; but again, this is just that - a reasonable approach, not a rule or a strict requirement, and you should feel free not to do so if you have reasons not to.

Let me explicitly clarify that what is said above stems from very fundamental principles; it is thus generally applicable, and it has nothing *specifically* to do with any scikit-learn internals.