# The loss function and evaluation metric of XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I am confused now about the loss functions used in `XGBoost`. Here is how I feel confused:

1. we have `objective`, which is the loss function needs to be minimized; `eval_metric`: the metric used to represent the learning result. These two are totally unrelated (if we don't consider such as for classification only `logloss` and `mlogloss` can be used as `eval_metric`). Is this correct? If I am, then for a classification problem, how you can use `rmse` as a performance metric?
2. take two options for `objective` as an example, `reg:logistic` and `binary:logistic`. For 0/1 classifications, usually binary logistic loss, or cross entropy should be considered as the loss function, right? So which of the two options is for this loss function, and what's the value of the other one? Say, if `binary:logistic` represents the cross entropy loss function, then what does `reg:logistic` do?
3. what's the difference between `multi:softmax` and `multi:softprob`? Do they use the same loss function and just differ in the output format? If so, that should be the same for `reg:logistic` and `binary:logistic` as well, right?

*supplement for the 2nd problem*

say, the loss function for 0/1 classification problem should be
`L = sum(y_i*log(P_i)+(1-y_i)*log(P_i))`. So if I need to choose `binary:logistic` here, or `reg:logistic` to let xgboost classifier to use `L` loss function. If it is `binary:logistic`, then what loss function `reg:logistic` uses?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280873/what-is-the-difference-between-loss-function-and-metric-in-keras

Comment: @JoshuaCook, it explains the first question, with Keras.

Comment: Yes, but your first question is conceptual in nature and not specific to library.

Comment: reg:logistic is usually calculating cost function as (y - y_pred)^2 and average over sample dimension.

Answer (score 12):

'binary:logistic' uses `-(y*log(y_pred) + (1-y)*(log(1-y_pred)))`

'reg:logistic' uses `(y - y_pred)^2`

To get a total estimation of error we sum all errors and divide by number of samples.

---

You can find this in the basics. When looking on Linear regression VS Logistic regression.

Linear regression uses `(y - y_pred)^2` as the Cost Function

Logistic regression uses `-(y*log(y_pred) + (y-1)*(log(1-y_pred)))` as the Cost function

---

Evaluation metrics are completely different thing. They design to evaluate your model. You can be confused by them because it is logical to use some evaluation metrics that are the same as the loss function, like `MSE` in regression problems. However, in binary problems it is not always wise to look at the `logloss`. My experience have thought me (in classification problems) to generally look on `AUC ROC`.

### EDIT

---

according to xgboost documentation:

> reg:linear: linear regression

> reg:logistic: logistic regression

> binary:logistic: logistic regression for binary classification, output
> probability

So I'm guessing:

reg:linear: is as we said, `(y - y_pred)^2`

reg:logistic is `-(y*log(y_pred) + (y-1)*(log(1-y_pred)))` and rounding predictions with 0.5 threshhold

binary:logistic is plain `-(y*log(y_pred) + (1-y)*(log(1-y_pred)))` (returns the probability)

You can test it out and see if it do as I've edited. If so, I will update the answer, otherwise, I'll just delete it :<

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Sounds like `reg:logistic` uses `rmse` as the loss (cost) function, which is more intuitive in `reg:linear`. I don't get why in logistic regression, why the `rmse` are still used, such that `y-y_pred` equals 1, 0, -1.

Comment: @BsHe Mate I think I'm mistaken. I will edit, you can check it and if it so, I'll fix the answer

Comment: I think we should keep the edit; the package author's answer seems verifies this https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/521#issuecomment-144453618. But I will wait to see if others give more solid answers.

Comment: @EranMoshe can you please confirm if the second half of logloss is y-1 ? I think it should be 1-y

Comment: @PaladiN Sorry mate. It should be 1-y (because we know y is in [0, 1)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, a loss function and evaluation metric serve two different purposes. The loss function is used by the model to learn the relationship between input and output. The evaluation metric is used to assess how good the learned relationship is. Here is a link to a discussion of model evaluation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html
2. I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here. Can you clarify this question?

Comment: I added some supplement for the 2nd question, thanks.

Comment: Still not following your question. What context are you asking these in?

Comment: let me make it simple. What loss function does `objective:'binary:logistic'` use, and what for `objective:'reg:logistic'`