# Difference between metric and loss MSE in tf.keras

Tags: keras, metrics, loss-function, mean-square-error

What are the differences between the mean squared error function in [tf.keras.metrics.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/mean_squared_error) and [tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError)?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280873/what-is-the-difference-between-loss-function-and-metric-in-keras) question. Mean squared error can be used as a loss function as well as a metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former is used as an indicator, and not used in the backpropagation calculation for updating the weights. It is used if you use other function as a loss function, but at the same time you also want to know the MSE value.